# filtering a dataframe in R based on how many elements in a Row are filled out

Tags: r

I have the following data frame (dput at end):

```
> d
   a  b  d
1  1 NA NA
2 NA NA NA
3  2  2  2
4  3  3 NA
```

I want to filter the rows that have at least two items that are not NA. I wish to get the result -- how do I do that?:

```
> d
   a  b  d
3  2  2  2
4  3  3 NA




> dput(d)

structure(list(a = c(1, NA, 2, 3), b = c(NA, NA, 2, 3), d = c(NA, 

NA, 2, NA)), .Names = c("a", "b", "d"), row.names = c(NA, -4L

), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `rowSums` of the logical matrix (`is.na(d)`), use that to create a logical vector (`..<2`) to subset the rows.

```
d[rowSums(is.na(d))<2,]
#  a b  d
#3 2 2  2
#4 3 3 NA
```

Or as @DavidArenburg mentioned, it can be also done with `Reduce`

```
df[Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, is.na)) < 2, ]
```

Comment: And the obligatory ```df[Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, is.na)) < 2, ]```.... Feels awefully familiar...

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, there might be dupes.  Feel free to tag it if you find one.